# How to make ListView loop?

Tags: android

I have created listView with about 20 items.
While navigating through keyboard when it's on last and when user hits down button I'd like it to go to first item.
Just like `keyNavigationWraps : bool` in QML.

Comment: Can you post some code to explain what have you done so far and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You should not iterate the list views, instead you should keep all that data (price/quantity) in a list and iterate over that if you really need to do that. That list can be used to populate the ListView as well.